# Identity relating floor function and hexagonal numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, geometric-intuition

While playing around with squares, I wondered about the sum of square roots of all natural numbers between two perfect squares(both inclusive). After taking the floor value of the expression for first few $n$ the numbers then obtained turned out to be $6,15,28,\ldots$. These are nothing but the [hexagonal Numbers](https://oeis.org/search?q=Hexagonal+numbers+&language=english&go=Search). That is,
$$ \lfloor \sum \limits_{h=0}^{2n+1} \sqrt{n^2+h} \rfloor = H(n+1) $$
Proving it was not a bit of a task, I started with truncating the Taylor expansion of the square root function and bounding the summand as follows :
$$n+\frac{h}{2n} -\frac{h^2}{8n^3} < \sqrt{n^2+h} < n + \frac{h}{2n}$$
Summing it all up and with little manipulation we get
$$ \lfloor \sum \limits_{h=0}^{2n+1} \sqrt{n^2+h} \rfloor = 2n^2+3n +1 = (n+1)(2(n+1)-1) = H(n+1) $$
Although I'm still struggling to find a more intuitive way which directly relates the sum with the very numbers.
Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: a similar [identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1362146p7467842) $\lfloor \sum \limits_{h=1}^{2n} \sqrt{n^2+h} \rfloor = 2n^2+n$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Also these becomes then the second hexagonal numbers generally denoted by A(n).